# Should my withdrawals be included on my transcripts for graduate admissions?

Tags: graduate-admissions, transcript-of-records, withdraw

When I first started college out of high school I attended a university for a few months before withdrawing. I received all W's on the transcript from that school. I am now about to graduate from a different university and am applying to different graduate schools.

Do I need to send the transcripts from this first school where I received the W's or do I only send transcripts from schools where I earned credit?

Answer (score 7):

This will depend on the schools that you're applying to. The best bet is going to be to call the admissions office and just ask.  Every application I've sent in has specifically stated *all colleges **attended***, but I suspect that your mileage may vary.

House-keeping note: Welcome to Ac.SO! Your question is fairly specific to your circumstances and so would be generally frowned upon as it doesn't really adhere to the format of the site. Check out the FAQ for more information on what a good SO question looks like.

Best of luck with your applications.